# Cauchy's Integral Formula: conditions vs singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm sure this is a simple misunderstanding but it was annoying me.

So using the version of Cauchy's Integral Formula given on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula, it is required that the function be holomorphic at every point in its domain. However as I understand it one of the primary uses of this theorem is to evaluate singularities but at these points the function is not holomorphic and so the theorem does not apply? The reason I say the function is not holomorphic is that certain functions (e.g. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$) are not continuous never mind differentiable.

Many thanks.

Comment: On the link I gave in the question, which has to be copy and pasted as just clicking the hyperlink only goes to Cauchy's page

Comment: It goes on to give an example dealing with poles but my confusion has been cleared up by Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the Cauchy Integral Formula is in this case is as follows:

$$\int_{C} f(z) dz = \int_C \frac{1}{z} dz = 1$$

We view the second integral as an integral of the analytic function 1 divided by $z$, which by the Cauchy formula the integral is equal to the function $1$ evaluated at zero.

Comment: So I've just misinterpreted its function. Rather than try to determine $\frac{1}{z}$ at $z=0$ we use this to evaluate the integral $\int_{C} \frac{1}{z} dz$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. We call the result of that integral the residue.